# User posts on a 3 years old Question that has an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues

While doing my first *First post reviews*, I stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5425981)

It **is** a good answer, but is on a 3 years old question with an already accepted answer.

What is the proper action to take on a case like this?

**Context :**

A user answered an **old** question that already has an **accepted answer**. That answer doesn't provide anything that the other answers haven't provided yet.

**Question :**

What would be the proper action to take in a case similar to that one?

Comment: Good answer? Upvote!

Comment: If it answers the question and it isn't a duplicate of an already existing answer on the post then do...nothing, unless you care to upvote if it is useful

Comment: I have no problem with a new, reasonable answer to an old question.  The things I'd like to stop are stupid edits (minor punctuation changes, etc) to old questions/answers, and "me too" answers.

Comment: "Notable Quotes: "Stay calm and grep away" - Chiedo John" - I like this guy already. Hope he stays around

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031/165773

Comment: @gnat That doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030/165773

Comment: @gnat How about you read the question to begin? And not auto-post links to general help-guidelines? Those two links provide nothing to my question. I am asking about a precise case.

Comment: The links that gnat provided do contain a wealth of general information on how to properly review late answers and first posts, so I'd say it's relevant information.  If you haven't read them yet, I encourage you to do so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Both links provide general guidelines on what to do in the review queues. Though they do not provide any help on this question. (First one, `Late Answers`, only has details on how to deal with spam and non-relevant answers. It says nothing about relevant answers that aren't helpful. Second link, `First posts`, only has details on link-answers, not-an-answer. Once again, it has nothing to do with my precise question, as the answer I refer to does answer the 3 years old question.)

Comment: Do you feel like your question is adequately addressed in the answers below?  FWIW, I disagree with your assertion that the answer you cited in your question doesn't add anything new.

Comment: The question is only old to the person who posted it.

Comment: @Col_Blimp: Actually, everyone can see the posting date.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Following your earlier [comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267222/user-posts-on-a-3-years-old-question-that-has-an-accepted-answer?noredirect=1#comment69850_267223), what would be the correct course of actions as a reviewer if it were to happen again? Because if I accept the upvoted answer, then reviewers might assume that it is always the good thing to do (upvote the answer even though it doesn't provide more value than the accepted answer did).

Comment: @Sifu: Honestly, I think that the general reference posts that Gnat linked already adequately cover this.  However, you can cast a custom moderator flag with an explanation; something like "This new answer on a very old post doesn't really add any value to an already good post."  If you're referring to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5425981), I don't think any action needs to be taken on it.

Comment: Robert Harvey, I know everyone can see the date and the op is likely long forgotten but the question is still valid and in the absence of it being closed it is inviting more answers so the question although old is not going to be old to someone else experiencing the same issue who wont create a new question as it would be a duplicate.

Comment: I regularly post to old questions where the answers leave out important details, new details have emerged, a lot of answers are wrong (*and and it is not clear they are wrong*) or are just in general not great. In fact there are badges such as [necromancer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) that encourage this. The reward usually takes a while to come in if at all but when it does it is awesome.

Comment: The meta effect is strong: 20 upvotes since yesterday, despite there being already another answer (not the accepted one) that gives almost the same information, is a year old, and has 16 upvotes.

Comment: since when does time matter? you upvote good answers and downvote bad answers. that's how SO works.

Comment: @sgroves But it also "Revives" an old question that was already answered long ago. Why place a question in the **active** list while it was answered 3 years ago?

Comment: @sifu why does that matter ?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Treat it like any other answer. If it's a good answer, upvote it. If it's a bad answer (wrong information, duplicating an existing answer,...), downvote it.

The age doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, it matters some... If it shows up in the moderator queue and it doesn't add substantial value to the answers that are already there, I'll generally delete it.  New answers that show up on very old posts are at higher risk of being things we don't want, like spam or "I don't understand your answer, can you elaborate?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey So if a question was answered an hour after it was asked, and someone else answers it a day later without adding substantial value (so it could be considered *not useful*), it gets to stay? Why make a difference?

Comment: No, that's not what I said.  I said that, if you're answering a question that was well-answered *three years ago,* you'd better be improving the post in some way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey OK, I can agree with that. But should a similar situation where a question is not that old be handled differently? Shouldn't the user also edit the existing answer/post a comment instead of posting a new answer?

Comment: What user?  The one that posted the original answer?  In general, I don't favor users updating other people's answers to make them current; they can always post a new answer with the current information, just as the example cited in the question here has done.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I often delete a draft answer without posting it because I see the 3 minute old question has been well-answered. Are you saying that it is appropriate to post answers to new questions that do not improve the post in some way?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think I might not be reading your comments correctly, it's been a long day. I'll go over it again when I get home :)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I never said that.  My comments here only address three-year-old posts.  To be clear, I'm not dictating policy here; I'm merely summarizing my own thinking, which is: if you're gonna bump a three-year-old post with a new answer, it had better be a good one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry, I was confused by your use of "very old" and emphasis on "three years ago". I thought that you were suggesting question age has some relevance. I think the criteria for posting answers, upvoting them, downvoting them, and deleting them should be completely independent of the age of the question.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Age does matter (some).  If it's a highly-localized troubleshooting question that was adequately solved three years ago, then why are you trying to solve it now?  If it's a popular post with tons of views that already has stellar answers, what value do you feel you are contributing with your new answer that will make the post better?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree with everything you say after "Age does matter" except that I would not try to solve now a question that was adequately solved 3 minutes ago.

Comment: Right.  But many people do.  That's why you have these softball posts with six new answers that say exactly the same thing.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, I think an answer that is simpler should be appreciated, regardless of age.  Someone could write 3000 lines of code that could do the same thing and get the accepted answer because it was first, but I'd prefer to see the simplest way to do something.  In fact, if it was my question and I saw a new, simpler answer, I would even want to change my accepted answer to the newer one.

Comment: @ps2goat Yes, a clearly better solution should be posted, upvoted, and possibly accepted as appropriate, regardless of question age.

Answer (score 52):

This question arises from two fundamental mistakes.

The first mistake is with the claim that the linked example "doesn't provide anything that the other answers haven't provided yet" and the claim in Sifu's comments that it is correct.

**In fact, the linked example finds fault with the other answers, and proposes a different method**

Therefore, one of three things is the case:

1. The new answer is wrong
2. The existing answers are wrong, making the new one an important contribution
3. The correct answer varies depending on details of the situation which have not been presented/discussed.  In this case all of the answers are useful contributions, but the question could benefit from additional contributions **by knowledgeable parties** to explain the difference

It is worth noting, that in all three of these cases, the best action for a third party to take is likely to leave comment(s) explaining the technical realities.  Case three might be cause for yet another answer, but none of these really require site-maintenance actions (flag, delete, etc).

The second mistake is the assumption that a reviewer has a responsibility to take action at all.  Put simply, if it is unclear what action to take, **skip the post**.

Comment: or 4. the existing answer(s) were perfectly correct but are now outdated as more recent versions of the relevant programs do something different. You could argue this is subsumed by 2. Still the conclusion is unchanged.

Comment: Actually, version dependency is a case of #3 - the best answer depends on details of the situation.  Ie, old answer is still correct for the situation of the original question it answers, but a different answer may be more useful for later readers with similar questions about a different version of the software.

Comment: You could see it as a version of #3. But it is a common variant of #3 and has a key difference with the *prototypical* instance of #3. Anyway, yes.

Answer (score 10):

Is the answer helpful?  This isn't a decision that takes place in a vacuum.

Consider a mediocre answer to a question that already has an amazing answer that includes all of the information of the mediocre answer and more, and with a superior presentation.  In such a situation the later answer simply isn't a helpful answer.  There aren't going to be people coming to the question and benefiting from reading that answer.  Either they read it instead of the other answer and get a lower quality answer, or they read both and have wasted their time reading the lower quality answer.  The community does not benefit from the existence of such an answer.  Voting is how the community provides such feedback.

Of course there are plenty of ways for an answer posted to a 3 year old question that already has an answer to be helpful.  The new answer could be of higher quality, it could be an alternate solution that may be superior for at least certain readers, etc.  If it would benefit the community for this answer to exist, even in the presence of the other answers to the question, then the votes should indicate its value.  Just because *an* answer exists doesn't mean that there's no way for any subsequent answer to be helpful.

It's also worth mentioning that there will likely be plenty of cases when looking at posts through the First Posts review queue that you won't be able to tell whether the post is adding or removing value, due to a lack of experience in the subject matter at hand.  In such cases you can absolutely evaluate the post for all sorts of other issues, but you should abstain from voting on the post if you don't feel that you're qualified to judge whether or not a particular post is truly helpful to readers looking for an answer to that question.

Comment: I generally agree, but the review queue does present answers in a sort of vacuum. Although of course one can open the link to question itself...

Comment: @900sit-upsaday As per my last edit, this isn't really the primary purpose of the queue.  It's main goal is not to have people judge the value of the post from a technical perspective.  Votes on the post are much more of a secondary goal of the queue.

Comment: I agree with you, but that doesn't answer my question : What is the proper action to take? (Upvote, downvote, flag, other?) Even though it is true that it doesn't benefit anyone reading that question, it is still a valid answer, no?

Comment: @Sifu The answer may be technically correct.  That doesn't make the answer automatically helpful.  It doesn't mean that you should upvote the answer without considering any other factors.  There are plenty of answers that are correct but not helpful.  It sounds like you're explaining one such example.

Comment: @Sifu Quite simply, if you cannot judge the answer, the proper action to take is to skip it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Just because you don't feel comfortable voting on the post due to lack of expertise in the subject doesn't mean that there isn't anything else that you may be able to review for that post.  There are plenty of problems that could be discussed or resolved without evaluating the technical usefulness of the post.  Even if you don't vote you can still edit, comment, flag, etc.

Comment: ... thus leading to the problem of **important** answers being removed by people who don't know enough about the subject to realize that they are important.

Comment: @ChrisStratton And the next person who gets it, what should he do? Skip it? Please..

Comment: Skip it as well, if he or she lacks sufficient knowledge of the subject matter to judge the worth of the contribution.  There really is no harm in non-abusive posts on less popular topics being processed slowly - if **the people who care about those topics** have a problem with them, they will eventually be dealt with, and if not, then there is no issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton This has nothing to do about sufficient knowledge of the subject matter. The answer gets upvoted/downvoted if it is correct or not. The matter here is if it is worth to permit an answer to be posted on a 3 years old already answered question. The new answer doesn't add anything valuable, but is still a correct answer. What do you do? Upvote? Vote to close for...?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Once again.  The first posts queue isn't there solely to vote on posts.  It's not even the *primary* purpose of the queue.  Just because you don't know enough about the subject to vote on the post doesn't mean you skip it.  If you don't have any idea what action should be taken in any way *then* you skip it.  If you see several problems that you can fix or issues to address without the use of voting then that's what you go do.

Comment: @Sifu You upvote an answer if it's **useful**.  Incorrect answers usually aren't useful, but not all correct answers are useful.  If you feel that the post is useful, you upvote it, if you feel that the post is not useful, you downvote it.  Whether the post is technically correct is just one of many considerations used to determine if the post is useful.

Comment: @Servy - I am not talking about voting, but about administrative actions, such as deciding if an old post is a technically useful contribution as suggested above, or beginning the process of removing it for not being so, again, as suggested above (as suggested above).

Comment: @Sifu - "The new answer doesn't add anything valuable, but is still a correct answer." seems untrue; the new answer **contradicts** the existing answers, so one of them is wrong or context-variable.  Are you able to determine which?  If not, leave it for someone who can.

Comment: @Servy So, according to you, if an answer is **correct** but **not useful**, reviewers should press the button "No action needed". Right?

Comment: @ChrisStratton The vast majority of actions one can take on a post besides voting require little or no domain knowledge, which the the reason that the queue can exist in the first place, as there are lots of productive actions to be performed by pointing people to potentially problematic posts outside of their given areas of expertise.  If there is nothing for someone to do on a post they don't understand the subject matter of there's no reason to have the queue at all.

Comment: @Sifu No.  If an post is not useful you should downvote it, to indicate to all future readers that the post is not useful.  And for a "first post" it would likely be worth taking the time to explain why the post is not useful to the author, in a comment.

Comment: Then maybe we shouldn't have topic-agnostic queues.  They seem to routinely cause huge amounts of trouble for less widely understood topics, with administrative actions taken based on gross misunderstanding by the reviewers.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You simply need to recognize that there are plenty of topic-agnostic actions that one can take on a post.  Those actions are the primary purpose of the existence of the queue, it's not just a way to get people to vote on posts.  The homepage is *far* better at accomplishing that.

Comment: Again, I am not speaking of up/down voting, but of administrative actions.  Less popular topics routinely get huge amounts of abuse of those actions (50% of posts) from ignorant reviewers.

Comment: @ChrisStratton While there is plenty of inappropriate actions taken, that's not a function of people lacking domain knowledge, that's a function of people not knowing how to properly use those moderation tools.  You don't need to know anything about the domain of the question to edit it to improve it's spelling/grammar/formatting, or to recognize spam, a non-answer, offensive content, etc.  Forcing people to review content in their domain of knowledge won't change any of that.

Comment: Given that some of this action is being taken by *moderators*, it actually is because they do not understand the topics well enough to apply the (presumably familiar) moderation tools *usefully*.  I haven't said anything about *forcing* people *to review* content, rather I've spoken of cautioning people against acting outside the limits of their expertise.

Comment: @ChrisStratton People apply moderation tools incorrectly within their areas of expertise all the time too.  Moderating is hard, people misunderstand posts all the time.  It happens.  It's not tied to the subject matter of the posts.  Telling people to skip every post not in a subject matter they're familiar with is simply not in line with the design of the queue.  You should skip a post only when you don't know what moderation actions should be taken.  If it was incorrect for anyone to ever review a post outside of their area of expertise there would be no point in having the queues at all.